# Two-Way-Authentication via Email in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Hello guys, I'm workin on a two-way-authentication with nodejs and expressjs. In my website you will have to login first. If the login was successful, the user will get an email with a key and a link where he has to paste that key. If the user opens that link and pastes that key, I want the user to be logged in. But currently the user is not logged in when I call the passport.authenticate() function in my code. The method successfully redirects to the users-page, that means that the login is successful but still no user is logged in.

```
router.post('/loginTwo/:token', function(req, res) {
async.waterfall([
function(done) {
  User.findOne({ twoWayAuthentication: req.params.token, authenticationExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'password-token has expired');
      return res.redirect('back');
    }

    if (user.twoWayAuthenticationPassword == req.body.twoWayAuthenticationPassword) {

        user.twoWayAuthenticationPassword = undefined
        user.twoWayAuthentication = undefined;
        user.authenticationExpires = undefined;
        console.log(reqlogin.body);
        console.log(req.body);
        user.save(function(err) {
            passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/users/',
            failureRedirect: '/',
            failureFlash : true 
            })(reqlogin, res);
          done(err, user);
        });
    }

  });
}
```

]);
});

As I said successRedirect: 'users' is called but when I check if the user is logged in, it shows he is not. In my function router.post('login'), I check if the username and password are matching with the data the user has written in req.body.username and req.body.password. If I call the function passport.authenticate function there, the user is logged in successfully, because the req of that function contains the username and the password of the user. So I saved the req of the function in a variable called reqLogin and passed that to the passport.authenticate() function in router.post('/loginTwo/:token'....). The req of the function loginTwo contains just a token, thats why it showed an error when I tried to call passport.authenticate() with it's req.